# PL/SQL: ORA-04063: view "OPS$DTEPROD.DTE_BLMB_TRD_ACCT_VW"

Tags: oracle

I have a view, which created  (ORACLE)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "OPS$DTEPROD"."DTE_BLMB_TRD_ACCT_VW"     
                ("BB_TRD_ACCT", "DESCRIPTION", "ICI_TRD_ACCT") AS    
select  rtrim(STRBK_BOOK_NAME) bb_trd_acct, 
        rtrim(STRBK_DESCRIPTION)    description, 
        trading_acct ici_trd_acct   
from    spider.sp_struct_books@spdn b1
        , dte_trading_acct   
where   substr(rtrim(STRBK_BOOK_NAME),1,2)=ltrim(rtrim(fits_trading_Acct))   
and     strbk_last_update_date =   
          (select max(strbk_last_update_date) 
                from spider.sp_struct_books@spdn b2   
                 where   b2.strbk_book_number = b1.strbk_book_number)
```

In the package, when I compile it shows me an error

> 328/117  PL/SQL: ORA-04063: view "OPS$DTEPROD.DTE_BLMB_TRD_ACCT_VW" has
>            errors

Could you please help me to find the reason?

Thanks

```
Errors for PACKAGE BODY RATES_2DTE:    

LINE/COL ERROR    
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------    
328/1    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored    
328/117  PL/SQL: ORA-04063: view "OPS$DTEPROD.DTE_BLMB_TRD_ACCT_VW" has
     errors
```

Comment: Can you also tell us the output of `Show Errors;` ?

Comment: If you run the select indepndent of the create view does it run?

Comment: Please check in my original post, I edit it

Comment: it has spider.sp_struct_books@spdn  table, which , when I run gives me TNS error. This table in another database

Comment: Do you have access to spider schema sp_struct_books on link spdn?  (which I assume is a stored procedure returning a table structure?)

Comment: As I said above when I try to run query with that table, it gave me TNS error

Comment: I can select from this view without any problem

Comment: (Does *Simple-column-Name* allow for quotes?)

Answer (score 0):

Please execute following query with same user which get the outlined error:

```
 Select * from user_errors where name like 'OPS$DTEPROD.DTE_BLMB_TRD_ACCT_VW';
```

This will give you errors in the view. You can post output for further investigations.

Regards
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve such problem I have to work with our DBA. Only they can give access to this database from development server. On production we have everything done.

Thank you all for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

Their are two probabilities :
1) As another member (@xQbert) suggested - user who is used to created view do not have accesses to table over dB link.

2) Database, used in database link, is not accessible.

Solution: 
1) Please execute following statement by same user which is trying to select from view:

```
Select count(*) from spider.sp_struct_books@spdn  ;
```

This should give same error as original error.

We want to check is read access to destination table is in place.

2) From server/command prompt on database host, where view is created, execute following :

```
tnsping spdn (or tnsping <database name usec by db link>)
```

OR

```
sqlplus <Username>/<Password>@spdn (or <database name usec by db link>)
```

We want to check if destination database on dBlink is reachable.

- Abhi